# Nesting instances of the same generator in Python

Tags: python, generator, nested-loops

Say I've got a generator:

```
def mygen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

This works as I would expect: all combinations of `i` and `j`

```
for i in mygen():
    for j in mygen():
        print i, j
```

I would think these are different instances.  Why are they not acting as different instances?

```
g1 = mygen()
g2 = mygen()

for i in g1:
    for j in g2:
        print i, j
```

If I try `g1.next()`, I get an error because there is no data left.

I'm running Python 2.7.1.

Comment: The first snippet calls `mygen` 11 times, while the second - only twice. Sapienti sat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterating over `g2` the first time consumes it, so there's nothing left when you try to iterate over it subsequent times.

```
g1 = mygen()
for i in g1:
    g2 = mygen()
    for j in g2:
        print i, j
```

Comment: Right.  To be specific, in the OP's example where he uses `for j in mygen():`, he is instantiating a new generator for each value of `i`.

Comment: Aah, yes.  I guess that was sort of a stupid mistake.  I've been using Python for a bit, but thinking in terms of generators is still a bit new for me.  Thanks!